# How can I use regular expressions to add an onclick event to words of a text in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to use regular expressions to add an onclick event to all the words of a text in React. I have tried to do it in two different ways so far, but none of them worked.
First I tried:

```
return(
   <div>
      <p>{textString.replace(/\w+/g,`<span onClick=handleSearch('$&')>$&</span>`)}</p>
   </div>
)
```

'textString' is a string with the text.
With this attempt, I managed to add the onclick event to the words, but all the result is inside of a new string, so the span tags are shown on the page.

After that I tried to use innerHTML.

```
useEffect(() =>{
   let text = textString.replace(/\w+/g,`<span onClick=handleSearch('$&')>$&</span>`)
   document.getElementById('text-placeholder').innerHTML = text
},[])

return(
   <div>
      <p id="text-placeholder">Placeholder</p>
   </div>
)
```

This attempt worked a bit better. I managed to add the onclick event to all the words and everything is displayed properly on the page. However, when I click on a word, I get the following error in the console.

"Uncaught ReferenceError: handleSearch is not defined at HTMLSpanElement.onclick"

I don't know what this error means, but the function isn't working.

Does anyone know how I can use regular expressions to add an onclick event to every word of a text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create new JSX elements instead of strings with the `.replace`. Match words or non-words and map to an array instead.

```
return (
    <div>
        <p>{
            textString
            .match(/\w+|\W+/g)
            .map(match => (
                /\W/.test(match)
                    ? match // plain string
                    : <span onClick={() => handleSearch(match)}>{match}</span> // JSX element
            ))
        }</p>
    </div>
)
```

Demo:

```js
const handleSearch = str => console.log('searching', str);
const textString = 'foo bar ###';
const App = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <p>{
                textString
                .match(/\w+|\W+/g)
                .map(match => (
                    /\W/.test(match)
                        ? match // plain string
                        : <span onClick={() => handleSearch(match)}>{match}</span> // JSX element
                ))
            }</p>
        </div>
    )
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```